# PHP to JSON How to get all entries?

Tags: php, arrays, json

here is a example how i get my json entries

```
$Json['members'][0]["name"];
$Json['members'][1]["name"];
```

How can i get all names suddenly?
[1,2] dosnt work

Comment: `var_dump($json);` ?

Comment: `foreach(){}` is the platinum standard of looping PHP arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$allNames = array_map(function($item){return $item["name"];}, $Json['members']);
print_r($allNames);
```

Suddenly prints all the names, no matter how many entries there are in the array.

If you aim the output to be more human-readable, use:

```
echo join(', ', $allNames);
```

instead of `print_r`.

Comment: This works... this is my output Array ( [0] => Vtins [1] => Humex [2] => tom [3] => kathy [4] => jose [5] => hhhh )  How can i get only the names Vtins Humes tom kathy jose hhhh without [1] [2] in my output ?

Comment: @Veltins, I've added this to the answer. You'll get: `Vtins, Humex, tom, kathy, jose, hhh`.

Comment: Yeeeess it works thanks v much Alex & all another :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad that I could help :)